# Can the DataGridView header automatically resize itself?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Is there a feature in datagrids that will automatically resize itself (the headers) depending on the longest characters in its column?

For example, if I have a long sentence, my datagrid header will automatically resize itself so that the message won't be cut.

Comment: Just as a note, there is both a `DataGrid` and a `DataGridView` control in WinForms. The `DataGridView` has replaced the `DataGrid` control, but both are still available. You need to make sure to distinguish between them and be clear about which one you're using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [DataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autosizecolumnsmode.aspx) property.

For instance,

```
dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells;
```

Comment: As a note - you will have to do some extra work to re-size the columns if the data is changing.