# Auto Resize Rows Header Height in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21442156/datagridview-put-text-in-columnheader-of-rowheader), how can I automatically resize the rows header height. It is actually the first column with index -1.

I tried:

```
datagridview.AutoResizeColumnHeadersHeight ();
datagridview.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
datagridview.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
```

Illustration:

[image]

```
datagridview.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayCells;
```

and

```
datagridview.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
```

are both not working for me (see illustration).

It fits well the columns from index 0 and up. But the column with index -1 is not being auto-resized as expected.

Comment: accepted
Use DataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode Property property.

For instance,

`dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can the DataGridView header automatically resize itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691951/can-the-datagridview-header-automatically-resize-itself)

Comment: @combo_ci, please see my edit